# How to change Black Theme to White Theme in runtime?

Tags: android, android-manifest

i need to know how to change the blackTheme to White Theme(light Theme) in all Activities of app by pressing two buttons, one is for black theme and the other is for white theme. I know how to set the themes in manifest and set the themes on `OnCreate` Method... but to change dynamically i dont know !! =(

can somebody help me please ?

obs: i know how to change(in runtime) the color of the buttons of my app...unless the background !

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are setting the theme by calling `setTheme()` before `setContentView()` in your `onCreate()` callback method. If you call `setTheme()` after `setContentView()` you will have to restart the activity.. I'm not very experienced changing themes during runtime tho.. but anyway, I could think of something like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int theme = getIntent().getIntExtra("theme", <INSERT DEFAULT THEME.. MAYBE FROM PREFS>);
    setTheme(theme);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notes_list)
}
```

the "light-theme" button restarts the activity with a new theme value which is stored in the intent:

```
public void onClickLightButton(View view) {
    finish(); 
    Intent i = getIntent();
    i.putExtra("theme", android.R.style.Theme_Light);
    startActivity(i);
}
```